# Druid SQL Query Rollup and Cube not working

Tags: olap, olap-cube, druid

I am using druid for OLAP on Bigdata. Connecting druid through java using JDBC avatica connection.
Everything working fine but when using the rollup and cube function in SQL query, not given the rollup aggregation row. Please help to get the rollup aggregated row.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[Rollup](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/index.html#rollup) occurs at ingestion time (like a `GROUP BY` on `__time` and your other dimensions).  If you have roll-up turned on, your query will be acting on rolled-up rows.  I hope that makes sense?

This video is good at explaining what the Rollup Feature is and might help you find exact configuration you need to check, particularly the [`queryGranularity`](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/index.html#granularityspec) which sets how `__time` is truncated at ingestion time.

https://imply.io/videos/druid-rollup

And this is the tutorial:

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-rollup.html